# How to check if hardware raid is working fine without pull HDD out and resetting?

Tags: raid, hardware-raid

I think the title says it all but here are some details:

1. I have a hardware RAID setup.
2. Machine is AMD 6core with MSI 890FXA motherboard.
3. I have two hard drives of 1TB each with hard ware RAID1 setup.

I want to know what's the best way to see if the RAID is working fine.

Comment: Step 1: Backup important data....

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be 100% certain you HAVE TO pull the disks one at a time and let them rebuild in between.

Do NOT trust the status given to you by your raid controller or any other piece of hardware/software.

I just had one disk die in my RAID 1 + hotspare setup and my Dell 2650 server with Perc 3/Di raid controller and the data went back in time 5 years!!!! (the server has been in operation for 6 years no and was due to be de-commissioned in the next few weeks)

It turns out that RAID broke 5 years ago and everything was being done on one disk only.
Even though all BIOS and other messages from the raid controller, Dell Openmanage software, etc. gave me a green light on its status, it wasn't actually doing what it said it was doing.

Answer (score 1):

If your point number 1 refers to the built-in hardware raid on the motherboard, the best way is to press `<CTRL-F>` when booting.

This brings you to the RAID options, where you can check the status of the RAID. From looking at the various BIOS screens, it actually seems like it is the 'Delete LD Menu' option, that best shows you the status of the RAID (**NOTE:** Please try the other options before using this one).

Comment: Keep in mind that different RAID controllers have different key combinations to enter the setup.